# How to execute Open and Close function on multiple text files?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying below code but for some reason, it is not workning as the logic suggest.

```
myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files,*.txt", , , , True)

On Error Resume Next
filecount = UBound(myTxt)
On Error GoTo 0

If filecount = 0 Then MsgBox "No text file selected. Exiting now.", _
    vbExclamation: Exit Sub

For i = LBound(myTxt) To filecount
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Debug.Print fnum
    Open myTxt(i) For Input As #fnum
    lines = Split(Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum), vbNewLine)
    Close #fnum

    '~~> Do stuffs here for text parsing...
Next
```

Basically, I want to work on multiple `.txt` files, open and load it to array.
Then close, do stuffs on the array and repeat the step for the succeeding files.
But it only gives me the parsing result for the 1st file.
Did I miss something in my code? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I checked the loop and it is working just fine for me

Comment: Yes, it is workning. I think what I'm missing is something in between the actual Open and Close routine.

Comment: Out of interest, I tested this with Excel 2010 (works fine as is) and Excel 2007 (does _not_ work: `GetOpenFilename` returns only a single file name, no matter how many are selected, so MsgBox is triggered and Sub exits)

Comment: Sorry mates. Silly mistake. I missed clearing some of my variables within the loop. That makes the parsing only execute once. Both above and @SiddharthRout 's code works.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks mate but I've tried it as well in 2007 but I did not encounter what you described.

Comment: @L42 Hmmm, interesting...

Comment: @L42, I guess that makes this non-reproducable...

Comment: @chrisneilsen actually closing this as soon as you guys read it,. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Posted as answer to avoid confusion:** What makes the code elude parsing all the text files:

```
For j = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
    If mydate = 0 Then If IsDate(Trim(lines(j))) Then mydate = CDate(Trim(lines(j)))
    If UpdatePage(lines(j)) Then page = page + 1

        Select Case True
        Case page = 1
        Case page = 2
        .
        .
        Case page = 4
        End Select
    End If
Next
'page = 0
'mydate = 0
```

The commented line is what I missed in my original code.
So the `Select Case` routine is ignored since `page` did not reset.
So there's really no problem on the code itself.
Current code and what Siddharth Rout posted is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version (TRIED AND TESTED).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long, filecount As Long
    Dim myTxt

    myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files,*.txt", , , , True)

    On Error Resume Next
    filecount = UBound(myTxt)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If filecount = 0 Then MsgBox "No text file selected. Exiting now.", _
    vbExclamation: Exit Sub

    For i = LBound(myTxt) To filecount
        'Debug.Print myTxt(i)
        Open myTxt(i) For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        'Debug.Print UBound(strData)
        '~~> Do stuffs here with strData for text parsing...
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got it figured. My current code and your code works fine. I editted my question adding the source of error. Thanks. Silly mistake really.