# Text to column while concatenating select values

Tags: vba, excel

I would just like to know if there is a simple way of doing a `TextToColumns` like command where it gets an `array` and just joins parts of that array down a column.

Example:

> Slected TextToColumns string in cell A2: John Doe 1:00 PM - 3:00 PM
>   Values to be pasted into cell B2: John Doe
>   Values to be pasted into cell C2: 1:00 PM
>   Values to be pasted into cell D2: 3:00 PM

The code I'm using now is a simple `TextToColumns` sequence:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A60").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1))
```

After the TextToColumns runs I have 3 `CONCATENATE` formulas to rejoin the values together. I figure there's probably a better way to handle that information

Comment: It depends on the size of your data. If you have like a thousand of lines, I'd still say that your method is the best. If it's not that big, maybe less than 100 lines, you can try looping through the Text file per line without loading it to Excel and just get the bits of info you need. You can start [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba) if you want to experiment on that route. I did a similar post [HeRe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354764/how-to-execute-open-and-close-function-on-multiple-text-files).

Comment: @L42 It's only going to be about 50 to 60 lines max.

Comment: The source also isn't from a text file. It's from within the same excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
dim c, arr

for each c in Range("A2:A60").cells
    If Len(c.value) > 0 then
        arr = split(c.value," ")
        c.offset(0, 1).value = arr(0) & " " & arr(1)
        c.offset(0, 2).value = arr(2) & " " & arr(3)
        c.offset(0, 3).value = arr(5) & " " & arr(6)
    End If
next c
```

Comment: The logic for the code looks good but for some reason I'm getting a "Compile Error" using that code when put in it's own `Sub Sorting()` and `End Sub` context.

Comment: Fixed - missing some `&`

Comment: Yep that did it. I also added an `On Error Resume Next` to the beginning to accommodate for blanks. Thanks